# I am having slideshow code in ImageView, But in addition to that I need to navigate to next next image while swiping

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

```
package cppandi.apjquotes;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class quotes extends AppCompatActivity {
int mFlipping = 0 ; // Initially flipping is off
Button mButton ; // Reference to button available in the layout to start and stop the flipper

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quotes);

    /** Click event handler for button */
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper1);

            if (mFlipping == 0) {
                /** Start Flipping */
                flipper.startFlipping();
                mFlipping = 1;
                mButton.setText(R.string.str_btn_stop);
            } else {
                /** Stop Flipping */
                flipper.stopFlipping();
                mFlipping = 0;
                mButton.setText(R.string.str_btn_start);
            }
        }
    };
    /** Getting a reference to the button available in the resource */
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    /** Setting click event listner for the button */
    mButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

I need to navigate to next corresponding image when user swipe the screen. Then what code should I use?

Here is my xml page with ViewFlipper and Imageview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/str_btn_start" />

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/flipper1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:flipInterval="3000"
    android:inAnimation="@anim/slide_in_right"
    android:outAnimation="@anim/slide_out_left"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
   //25 Images in imageview
</ViewFlipper>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then I need to know the usage of inAnimation and outAnimation.

Comment: You want to use `ViewPager` so simple slideshow

Comment: There is a great example in Android Training docs itself, Take a look https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: Jabbar is right, use a ``ViewPager``. If you then enrich your ViewPager together with the open source TouchImageView class you even have pan & zoom & doubletap functionality.
https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView